# v-alert display multiline text?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use a v-alert to display error messages that might come back from an api server, however I need to display more than one line and I can't seem to make that work.

Things I've tried:

Using a `<pre>` block inside the v-alert but then it looks peculiar with a monospaced font that looks like courier.

Manually putting a line break  `<br/>` in static text in the v-alert contents works but not if I then try to bind it to a data property of the same exact string which results in displaying the `<br/>` literally (i.e. `"test line one<br/>test line two"`).

I've tried a div block inside the alert with a style of `word-wrap: break-word;` but that doesn't work either it still shows as one line.

Any ideas on how to show mutiple lines in this component greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to your `v-alert` and set it to use `white-space: pre-line` in CSS, eg

```html
<v-alert
  :value="true"
  type="success"
  class="multi-line"
  >This is a
  success alert.</v-alert>
```

```css
.multi-line {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Just don't put any newlines before or after your text.

Demo ~ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWQvqO

Answer (score 3):

Try using v-html directive.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

This code works

HTML Code:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>      
      <v-alert
        :value="alert"
        type="success"
        transition="scale-transition"
      >
        <span v-html="datas"></span>
      </v-alert>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```javascript
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      alert: true,
      data1: 'Hello',
      data2: 'World!'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    datas() {
      return this.data1 + ' <br> ' + this.data2;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This absolutely works as well, but I chose the other solution only because it fits in better with other code but this is a very useful thing to know about and thank you for posting it.

Comment: This could be more vulnerable to XSS attacks though, right? You have to sanitize the string inputs any time you're using it to render HTML.